# How to disable an HTML anchor element onload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an `<a>` element which acts like a button that I want to be disabled on site load, and when a checkbox is checked, that `a` link will be clickable.

I have done this on an input of `type=button`, but the problem is that input buttons doesn't work with my smoothscroll effect.

Comment: Can you create a sample of what you have at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QBWTr/

This is what i have right now, before i came up to change the button to a link tag. I havent included the input button on the jquery code yet. Thanks

Comment: You can't use the disabled attribute on hyperlinks. It's for input elements.

Answer (score 1):

This should work nicely:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a id="alink" href="javascript:void(0);">Some Link</a>

<br /><br />

<input id="chkid" type="checkbox" value"" name="somename" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#chkid').unbind("click").click(function(){
var chkid = this.id;
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$("a#alink").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
}else{
$("a#alink").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This did worked nicely, Thanks a lot. However, i'd like to ask for another help, how or what should i add in my jquery smooth scroll code listed here http://jsfiddle.net/QBWTr/ so the enabled link doesn't just jump right onto it's linked <div id="#link">. Other 'a' works with this smooth scroll effect. Thanks again.

Comment: That's another question. If my solution solved your initial problem please mark as the answer. You need to post your FULL code, that includes your html along with JQuery on jsfiddle so others can see what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
button.dead {
   background: transparent;
   border: none
}

button.dean a {
   color: #ddd
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    // toggleWrap() function will call when user change the checkbox
    // wrap -> parameter contain true or false (which is chekcbox status)

    function toggleWrap(wrap) {
        // checking for the condition when checkbox is not checked
        if(!wrap) {
             // wrapping the <a> tag with a button which is 
             // disabled, so it will unclickable
             $('a').wrap($('<button/>', {
                disabled: true,
                'class': 'dead', // this class have some CSS
                 width: $('a').width()  // width of button change to <a> width
            })); 
        } else  {
            // following code will work when checkbox is not checked
            // .unwrap() function will remove the <button> wrapper from <a>
            // and unpack the <a> tag to clickable

            $('a').unwrap();
        }
    }

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {  // bind event to fire when user change the checkbox
        // this.checked hold the checkbox status
        // which is boolean true => if checked or false => if not checked
        toggleWrap(this.checked);
    });
    toggleWrap(false); // this is the initial call to function at page load
});​
```